# Create a stored procedure for a table named X

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
   ID int NOT NULL,
   ModifiedDate datetime,
   FirstName varchar(50),
   LastName varchar(50),
   EMail varchar(30),
   PhoneNumber varchar(15),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

GetX (int IDX)
```

if the parameter is null returns all the rows of the table ordered by ModifiedDate field in descending order

otherwise returns just the row that matches the ID

Comment: You mean a stored procedure in the database? You'll have to tell us which database you're using because the syntax varies. However please write the SQL to do the selects first, and then we'll help you make a stored procedure out of it if you still need help.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 3):

What you are wanting is a "catch all" query. For SQL Server, this can be done a couple of ways. [Aaron Bertrand writes about it here.](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)

```
create procedure GetX (@IDX int = null)
as

select
   ID
   ,ModifiedDate
   ,FirstName
   ,LastName
   ,EMail
   ,PhoneNumber
from Persons
where @IDX is null or ID = @IDX
order by ModifiedDate desc
```

Then

```
exec GetX @IDX = 4;
exec GetX @IDX = null;
```

Comment: I think a reference to Aaron Bertrand is worth an upvote.